# Help to pending Verification

Tags: wallet, payment, balance, verification, withdrawal

In cryptofree.casa How Long Take to pending Verification is over please help
My email is:
Hosseinnassari84@gmail.com[image]

Comment: Hi Hossein Nassari, could you please edit your question to provide more details? What are we looking at? What is the expected outcome? Who or what are you interacting with? Please note that if you are inquiring about the internal business processes of a company, we likely cannot help you because we don't have insight into that.

Comment: Cryptofree.casa its been 15 day in pending Verification

Comment: We just had another user ask about that site a few days ago. It doesn't look particularly trustworthy. Either way, we have no insight into the internal processes of sites, and we don't review services, so I'm afraid we can't help you with this one beyond some general advice how to evaluate services.

Comment: Can you give me a email or some adress from cryptofree.casa to ask my question from there

Comment: They don't seem to have contact details listed on their public site (which is a red flag), and I don't have an account there to check whether it's any different for users that are logged in. Either way, I have no knowledge of this service, so I'm afraid you'll have to dig in yourself.